# C++ 20 coroutines with PyBind11

Tags: python, c++, generator, pybind11, c++-coroutine

I'm trying to get a simple C++ 20 based generator pattern work with PyBind11. This is the code:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <coroutine>
#include <iostream>

struct Generator2 {
    Generator2(){}
    struct Promise;
    using promise_type=Promise;
    std::coroutine_handle<Promise> coro;
    Generator2(std::coroutine_handle<Promise> h): coro(h) {}
    ~Generator2() {
        if(coro)
            coro.destroy();
    }
    int value() {
        return coro.promise().val;
    }
    bool next() {
        std::cout<<"calling coro.resume()";
        coro.resume();
        std::cout<<"coro.resume() called";
        return !coro.done();
    }
    struct Promise {
        void unhandled_exception() {std::rethrow_exception(std::move(std::current_exception()));}
        int val;
        Generator2 get_return_object() {
            return Generator2{std::coroutine_handle<Promise>::from_promise(*this)};
        }
        std::suspend_always initial_suspend() {
            return {};
        }
        std::suspend_always yield_value(int x) {
            val=x;
            return {};
        }
        std::suspend_never return_void() {
            return {};
        }
        std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept {
            return {};
        }
    };
};


Generator2 myCoroutineFunction() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        co_yield i;
    }
}

class Gen{
private:
    Generator2 myCoroutineResult;
public:
    
    Gen(){
        myCoroutineResult = myCoroutineFunction();
    }

    int next(){
        return (myCoroutineResult.next());
    }
};


PYBIND11_MODULE(cmake_example, m) {
    pybind11::class_<Gen>(m, "Gen")
            .def(pybind11::init())
            .def("next", &Gen::next);
}
```

However I'm getting an error:

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Could c++ coroutines, coroutine_handles, co_yield etc. be a low-level thing that is not supported by PyBind11 yet?

Comment: Can you get a stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `PyBind11` does not support coroutines directly, your problem does not mix coroutine and pybind code since you are hiding the coroutine behind `Gen` anyway.

The problem is that your `Generator2` type uses the compiler provided copy and move constructors.

This line:

```
myCoroutineResult = myCoroutineFunction();
```

Creates a coroutine handle when you call `myCoroutineFunction`, and puts it in the temporary `Generator2` in the right hand side. Then, you initialize `myCoroutineResult` from the right hand side generator. All is well, but then the temporary gets destroyed. Your destructor checks whether the handle is valid or not:

```
~Generator2() {
    if(coro)
        coro.destroy();
}
```

But in your implementation, the `coro` member of the member generator gets copied from the temporary without resetting the temporary's `coro` member. So the coroutine itself gets destroyed once you initialize `myCoroutineResult`, and you are holding onto a dangling coroutine handle. Remember that `std::coroutine_handle`s behave like a raw pointer.

Essentially, you have a violation of the rule of 5. You have a custom destructor, but no copy/move constructors or assignment operators. Since you cannot copy construct a coroutine, you can ignore the copy constructors but you need to provide move constructors/assigment operators:

```
Generator2(Generator2&& rhs) : coro{std::exchange(rhs.coro, nullptr)} {
    // rhs will not delete our coroutine, 
    // since we put nullptr to its coro member
}

Generator2& operator=(Generator2&& rhs) {
    if (&rhs == this) {
        return *this;
    }
    if (coro) {
        coro.destroy();
    }
    coro = std::exchange(rhs.coro, nullptr);
    return *this;
}
```

Also, use member initialization list to initialize members instead of assigning them within the constructor body. So instead of this:

```
Gen(){
    myCoroutineResult = myCoroutineFunction();
}
```

Use this:

```
Gen() : myCoroutineResult{myCoroutineFunction()} {}
```

The reasoning can be seen even in this answer. The first one calls the assignment operator, which performs a bunch of additional work, whereas the second one calls the move constructor, which is as lean as it gets.

Comment: Great, explanation, thank you. So it seems the bug was essentially introduced because I had an additional assignment operation in the pybind wrapper for the generator which calls assignment semantics that weren't explicitly defined.